# Wrong iOS version shown in test flight

Tags: ios, testflight, ios6.1

My iPhone is running iOS 6.1.3 but Test flight captures the iOS version as 6.0.1 and refuses to install an app built for 6.1. 
Please suggest some solution to do a refresh if possible.

Comment: Have you tried contacting TestFlight?

Comment: yes. haven't got any reply till now.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the TestFlight app then reinstalling?  You've confirmed that the device is indeed running 6.1.3?  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting device?

Comment: I'd suggest unregistering you device from TestFlight and registering it again.